# python decoding/encoding hell (using jinja2)

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, jinja2

I am using jinja2 templating language in python to show a web site.

The relevant source code looks like:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    ...
    template_values = {'name': u'abwärtz'}
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('Home.html')
    print( template.render(template_values) )
    ...
```

---

The funny thing is if i use :

```
template_values = {'name': u'abw_rtz'}
```

everything works just perfect!

According to  [jinja2 s documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/)

> ...For Jinja2 the default encoding of templates is assumed to be
>   utf-8.
>
> ...To explicitly use a Unicode string you have to prefix the string
>   literal with a u: u'Hänsel und Gretel sagen Hallo'. That way Python
>   will store the string as Unicode by decoding the string with the
>   character encoding from the current Python module. If no encoding is
>   specified this defaults to ‘ASCII’ which means that you can’t use any
>   non ASCII identifier....

So, just use u'äöü' and everything should work, right?

This is what I get:

---

```
template_values = {'name': unicode('abwärtz','utf-8') }
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 3: invalid continuation byte
```

---

```
template_values = {'name': u'abwärtz' }
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

---

```
template_values = {'name': unicode('abwärtz',"ISO-8859-1") }
--> everything works just perfect!
```

---

I am working on Windows 7 and `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns ASCII.

Could someone explain this strange behavior?
I am searching for a solution where 'name': also handles chinese or cyrillic characters.

Comment: What editor are you using to write your code? Assuming my answer is right, someone can probably tell you how to configure almost any editor properly except Notepad (and if you're Notepad, the answer is to stop doing that).

Comment: I am using Notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely in the text editor you used to save this source file.

Source files are encoded bytes. Your editor has to decide how to store that `ä` character. On Windows, many text editors will default to your OEM code page, which is often a Latin-1 derivative called code page 1252, not UTF-8.

If you add a coding declaration to the top of the file telling Python the bytes are UTF-8, but those bytes aren't really UTF-8, but rather cp1252, Python is going to misinterpret them, leading to a `UnicodeDecodeError` if you're lucky, hard-to-track-down mojibake if you're not.

If you were already using Cyrillic or Chinese characters, the problem would likely have been more obvious, because trying to save a file with a Chinese character in it as cp1252 (which can't handle Chinese characters) would probably give you a warning or error with just about any editor. But saving western European characters as cp1252 (which can handle them) may just silently do the wrong thing. (There are a few editors—most notably emacs—that can share their coding declarations with Python, so if you try to save a file with that `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` it will either save as UTF-8 or give you a very stern warning. But most editors won't have any clue that you're lying in your coding declaration.)

---

How can you *verify* that this is the problem?

The easiest thing to do is view your source file in a hex editor (or just open it in binary mode and hexlify it in a Python script, if you prefer). If this really is UTF-8, you should see something like:

```
61 62 77 c3 a4 72 74 7a    a b w . . r t z
```

Whereas if it's cp1252, you'll see:

```
61 62 77 e4 72 74 7a       a b w ? r t z
```

The difference is the two `c3 a4` bytes (UTF-8 for 'ä') vs. the one `e4` (Latin-1, and cp1252, for 'ä').

---

At any rate, you have two solutions:

- Make sure you configure your editor to default to UTF-8, and convert your existing source files from cp1252 to UTF-8.
- Don't use any non-ASCII characters in the source; write `u'abw\u00e4rtz'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This discussion is very enlightening. Thank you all for engaging.

Here is what I did to solve my own case:

1. Download and install HxD, a free hex editor.
   (http://mh-nexus.de/en/downloads.php?product=HxD)
2. Use HxD to open the "text" file in question.
3. Set Charset to DOS/IBM-ASCII.
4. Visually review the "text" for odd "characters".
5. Replace those odd "characters" with those that are compatible with your requirements. The Search/Replace drop-down tool is very good for this.
6. Save the file when finished.